# IDLE keeps crashing on Mac when I try to install Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, python-idle

I've installed the Tk fix that was suggested on the official Python website but IDLE keeps crashing. I can paste the crash report code too if needed. I'm on Yosemite if it makes a difference.

Comment: Some more context would help - a specific error message (e.g. just the crash report) would help somewhat.

Comment: Also, what Tk fix? And exactly what steps do you take that lead to the problem?  Is there any information in the Console.app system log?

Comment: Have you checked existing bug reports and/or created a new one? I think you are barking up the wrong tree here, this is a bug in some piece of software and not a programming question.

Comment: Does tkinter itself run?  At command line, enter `python -m tkinter` (replace `python` by whatever you need to run 3.4.2 if different on your machine).  You should see tk window with text including 'cedilla' and two buttons.  If that works, try `python -m idlelib` and you should see an error message.  If you do get a message, post it.